# jQuery DataTable - all records are not displayed when placed in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to display data in jquery datatable which is placed in a bootstrap modal dialog but, for some reason, I am not able to see all the data. The jquery datatable is enabled with scroller instead of paging to display large data.

**JS Bin:** http://live.datatables.net/pujowuqo/2/edit

**Issue and Reproduction Steps:**

a. Launch the JS Bin
b. Do not resize the page
c. Click on launch demo modal button
d. Try to scroll and see the data. 
e. The data will be displayed partially and finally some of the records are missing

[image]

**Observation:**

If I resize the page, then all the data started displaying. I don't want to trigger window resize as it will affect other places in my project.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function () { 


  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    scrollY: '50vh',//setting fixed height also does not work
    scrollX: true,
    scroller: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    searching: false,
    paging: true,
    info: false,
    columns: [
      { title: "Name", data: "Name" },
      { title: "Email", data: "Email" },
      { title: "Title", data: "Title" }
    ]
  });

  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {


        table.columns.adjust().draw();

        var data = [];

        for (var count = 1; count <= 200; count++) {

            data.push({
                Name: "Test name of an user " + count,
                Email: "testuser.name@gmail.org",
                Title: "Title of the user will be displayed"
            });
        }

        table.clear().draw().rows.add(data);
        $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true }).scroller.measure();
    });

});
```

Comment: For me it's showing full records.

Comment: Did you try with out resizing the page or the output window in js bin?

Comment: Tell me the initial width of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

It's working while open on first time. If I left the scroll bar at the half or bottom. It's not showing the records. So try scroll back to top.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //Scroll back to top
    $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100);
    table.columns.adjust().draw();

    var data = [];

    for (var count = 1; count <= 200; count++) {

        data.push({
            Name: "Test name of an user " + count,
            Email: "testuser.name@gmail.org",
            Title: "Title of the user will be displayed"
        });
    }

    table.clear().draw().rows.add(data);
    $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true }).scroller.measure();
});
```

The working code: http://live.datatables.net/pujowuqo/4/
[image]

Comment: I tried your link but, it is sill not showing all records

Comment: Can you attach the snapshot in the answer section in half scroll?

Comment: The link is not working in my network. Is it possible to attach the snapshot as I have done in the question section? Thanks.

Comment: please check now.

Comment: It seems like all records are displayed. Is this behavior observed right after loading the dialog or after resizing the page?

Comment: This is what I am seeing when I tried your link: https://i.imgsafe.org/6454ace2ee.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127929/discussion-between-sarath-kumar-and-vimalan-jaya-ganesh).